# Nonlinear approximation with e-squared-function

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, regression, data-analysis

I have collected a few measurements (x and y coordinates) and would be interested in how to make a possible approach to the data with this function:
$$ y = a \cdot e ^ {b (x + c) ^ 2} $$

I have already made a linear regression, but I would be interested in a regression with the e-function. It must somehow be possible to deduce the e-function to a linear or polynomial case and to determine the parameters.
With the normal e-function, like $$ y=a \cdot e ^ {bx} $$ regression is possible, that's what I tested. But how to proceed with the e squared function?

Comment: Can someone explain where the downvote comes from so that I can improve my question?

Comment: The strings "e-function" or "e-squared-function" are non-standard and the last one does not make a sense to me. Indeed, I initial thought that "e" was short for error rather than exponential. I imagine the downvote is due to your use of non-standard notation. Certainly, the meaning of your notation can be deduced from your text, but try to write questions which make sense immediately to as many users as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Based on $n$ data points $(x_i,y_i)$, you want to adjust parameters $a,b,c$ of the model $$y = a \, e ^ {b \,(x + c) ^ 2}$$ As you noticed, the problem is $c$.

So, in a preliminary step, fix $c$ at a given value and define $t_i=(x_i+c)^2$. So
$y=a e^{b t}$ and taking logarithms
$$\log(y)=\log(a)+ bt=\alpha +b t$$ So, define $z_i=\log(y_i)$ and perform a linear regression which gives, for this value of $c$, $\alpha$ and $b$ and then $a=e^\alpha$. With these, compute the $y_i^{calc}$ and the sum of squares
$$SSQ(c)=\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i^{calc}-y_i)^2$$

Now, vary $c$ and plot $SSQ(c)$ and try to find a place where $SSQ(c)$ is close to a minimum. At that approximate value, you then know $a,b$ and you are ready for a nonlinear regression since you now have good estimates for each of the three parameters you are looking for.

If you have no nonlinear regression tool, just continue the procedure using smaller and smaller steps for parameter $c$.

You can do all of that using Excel.

**Edit**

You can get an approximate solution if you select from your data three points in arithmetic progression that is to say $x_1$, $x_2=x_1+d$,  $x_3=x_1+2d$. Using
$$\log(y_i)=\log(a)+b(x_i+c)^2$$ then
$$\log(y_2)-\log(y_1)=b d (2 c+d+2 x_1)$$
$$\log(y_3)-\log(y_1)=4 b d (c+d+x_1)$$
$$k=\frac{\log(y_3)-\log(y_1) } {\log(y_2)-\log(y_1) }=\frac{4 (c+d+x_1)}{2 c+d+2 x_1}\implies c=d \left(\frac{1}{k-2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)-x_1$$

For illustration purposes, let us use the following data set
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x & y \\
 0.5 & 630 \\
 1.0 & 360 \\
 1.5 & 230 \\
 2.0 & 170 \\
 2.5 & 140 \\
 3.0 & 120 \\
 3.5 & 130
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using $x_1=0.5$, $x_2=2.0$ and $x_3=3.5$ (that is to say the end points and the one in the middle, we get $c \approx -3.1363$. For this value, the linear regression leads to $\alpha=4.82282$, $b=0.233356$. So $a=124.315$.

Using these starting guesses, a full nonlinear regression would lead to the following results
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 124.485 & 2.2108 & \{117.450,131.521\} \\
 b & 0.234862 & 0.0077 & \{0.210415,0.259309\} \\
 c & -3.12729 & 0.0502 & \{-3.28701,-2.96756\} \\
\end{array}$$

**Edit after JJacquelin's answer**

When we use the traditional least square approach, what we minimize is
$$SSQ_1=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(y_i^{calc}-y_i^{exp} \right)^2$$ If you make a logarithmic tansform, what is minimized is 
$$SSQ_2=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\log(y_i^{calc})-\log(y_i^{exp}) \right)^2$$ which is not the same since what is measured is $y$ and not $\log(y)$; so, if you want to be rigorous, after the first step, you need to perform a nonlinear regression.

We can show that, using the logarithmic transform is *almost* equivalent to the minimization of
$$SSQ_3=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{y_i^{calc}-y_i^{exp} } {y_i^{exp} }\right)^2$$ since 
$$r_i=\log(y_i^{calc})-\log(y_i^{exp})=\log\left(\frac{y_i^{calc}}{y_i^{exp}} \right)=\log\left(1+\frac{y_i^{calc}-y_i^{exp}}{y_i^{exp}} \right)$$ and, if the absolute errors are small
$$r_i \approx \frac{y_i^{calc}-y_i^{exp}}{y_i^{exp}} \implies SSQ_2 \approx SSQ_3 $$ Minimizing $SSQ_3$ would give $a=124.117$, $b=0.23266$, $c=-3.14126$ which are very close to the numbers given by JJAcquelin.

If you look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html), you will notice that, for the least squares fitting of an exponential function, they suggest to minimize
$$SSQ_4=\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^{exp}\left(\log(y_i^{calc})-\log(y_i^{exp}) \right)^2$$ which does not make the problem more difficult. Using the same data, we should get $a=124.422$, $b=0.233604$, $c=-3.13423$.

Comment: Thanks for your edited Answer! But how did you come from $$ \log(y_i)=\log(a)+b(x_i+c)^2 $$ to $$ \log(y_2)-\log(y_1)=b d (2 c+d+2 x_1) $$

Comment: @user570694. Remember that I selected 3 points in arithmetic progression. Replace and expand.

Comment: @user570694. I have been stupid ! For the linearized step, write $$\log(y)=(\log(a)+c^2)+2bc x+b x^2=\alpha+\beta x+b x^2$$ which is abasic linear regression. When you have $\alpha,\beta,b$ then $c=\frac \beta{2b}$ and $a=e^{\alpha-c^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{Fitting of}\quad y=ae^{b(x+c)^2}\quad \text{to data :}$$ 
 $$ (x_1,y_1)\:,\: (x_2,y_2)\:,\: … \:,\:  (x_k,y_k) \:,\: … \:,\: (x_n,y_n).$$

A very simple calculus :

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
  C_1 \\
  C_2 \\
  C_3
 \end{matrix}\right)=
\left(\begin{matrix}
  \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^4 & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^3 & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 \\
  \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^3 & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k \\
  \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n 1
 \end{matrix}\right)^{-1}
\left(\begin{matrix}
  \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2\ln(y_k) \\
  \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\ln(y_k) \\
  \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \ln(y_k)
 \end{matrix}\right)
$$
$$a=e^{\left(C_3-\frac{C_2^2}{4C_1} \right)}$$
  $$b=C_1$$
  $$c=\frac{C_2}{2C_1}$$
EXAMPLE :

From Claude Leibovici's data : $\quad\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x & y \\
 0.5 & 630 \\
 1.0 & 360 \\
 1.5 & 230 \\
 2.0 & 170 \\
 2.5 & 140 \\
 3.0 & 120 \\
 3.5 & 130
\end{array}
\right)$

The result of the above method is : 
$\quad
\begin{cases}
a=124.249 \\
b=0.232567 \\
c=-3.140717
\end{cases}
\quad$

very close to the C.Leibovici's results :
$\quad
\begin{cases}
a=124.485 \\
b=0.234862\\
c=-3.12729 
\end{cases}$ .

**Edit after C.Leibovici's comments**

The change of criteria of fitting suggested in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html

in fact consists to a weighted regression with weight $=\frac{y}{\ln(y)}$.

With this trick, the least mean square relative regression becomes approximately (but not exactly) a least mean square regression.

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
  C_1 \\
  C_2 \\
  C_3
 \end{matrix}\right)=
\left(\begin{matrix}
  \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^4 \frac{y_k}{\ln(y_k)} & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^3 \frac{y_k}{\ln(y_k)} & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 \frac{y_k}{\ln(y_k)} \\
  \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^3 \frac{y_k}{\ln(y_k)} & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 \frac{y_k}{\ln(y_k)} & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k \frac{y_k}{\ln(y_k)} \\
  \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 \frac{y_k}{\ln(y_k)} & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\frac{y_k}{\ln(y_k)}  & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{y_k}{\ln(y_k)} 
 \end{matrix}\right)^{-1}
\left(\begin{matrix}
  \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 y_k \\
  \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k y_k \\
  \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n y_k
 \end{matrix}\right)
$$
$$a=e^{\left(C_3-\frac{C_2^2}{4C_1} \right)}\quad;\quad b=C_1\quad;\quad c=\frac{C_2}{2C_1}$$

Using the same data, we get $a=124.386$, $b=0.233374$, $c=-3.13566$.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jean ! A good solution as usual. There is just a problem (I knwo that I am maniacal on this topic) : what is measured is $y$ and not any of its possible transform. In fact (I shall edit in my answer), taking logarithms and fitting corresponds to the minimization of relative errors.

Comment: Would you mind to redo your calculation using equation (5) at  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html ? It could be very interesting (at least to me !). Cheers.

Comment: Hi Claude ! Often the Physicians prefer the minimization of the relative errors. May be you too. For me it doesn't matter relative error, or absolute error, or squared errors : I am not Statistician. But I like to get angry the kind of statisticians who swear only by least mean square errors.

Comment: Hi Jean ! To tell the truth, being initially a physicist and for many years in charge of the "best" representation of physical properties, I always minimize the sum of squares of relative errors. May I confress that I agree, at the level of  $10^{123456789}$%, with your last sentence ?

Comment: When I gave the link to the paper from Wolfram, what was interestiong to me was the multiplication of the residue $r_i$ by $\sqrt{y_i}$. That's all.

Comment: In the paper from wolfram, the fitted function is $y=Ae^{Bx}$ which is very different from $y=ae^{b(x+c)^2}$. . Minimizing Eq.$(5)$ leads to $A\simeq 738.174705$ ; $B\simeq -0.614926$ . My comment has changed because of a code mistake now corrected. The fitting to  $y=Ae^{Bx}$ to your data is very bad. Clearly this exponential function is not convenient, while the function $y=ae^{b(x+c)^2}$ fits rather well.

Comment: See the addition to my answer. Cheers.